# Stacking "points" for every X over max value

Tags: python

I'm a python newbie and currently learning on basics with it. I've come across this task and I would really love to solve it so I can understand how to do similar things in the future. Here is how it goes : Write a function for checking the speed of drivers. This function should have one parameter: speed.
If speed is less than 70, it should print “Ok”.
Otherwise, **for every 5km above the speed limit (70), it should give the driver one demerit point** and print the total number of demerit points. For example, if the speed is 80, it should print: “Points: 2”.
If the driver gets more than 12 points, the function should print: “License suspended”

This is what I came up with currently, but can't solve bolded part of text. Would appreciate it if you could help me. Thanks !

```
def speed_check(speed):
warning_point = 0
max_speed = 70
if (speed <= max_speed):
    print ("OK")
elif (speed >=130):
    print ("Licence suspended, you total warning points is 12.")
elif ("something must go here"):
    warning_point +=1
    print("Current warning point is {0}".format(warning_point))
```

speed_check(75)

Answer (score 0):

A global variable will be needed to keep track of how many warning points have been awarded. Below should do it, comment if it makes sense or if there are parts you want explaining.

```
def speed_check(speed):
    global warning_point
    max_speed = 70
    if speed <= max_speed:
        print ("OK")
    else:
        warning_point += (speed-max_speed) // 5
        print("Current warning point is {0}".format(warning_point))

    if warning_point >= 12:
        print("Licence suspended, you total warning points is at least 12.")


warning_point = 0

speed_check(75)
speed_check(85)
speed_check(115)
```

Comment: Thanks, my brain couldn't come up with (speed-max_speed) // 5. Now I realize how you get 1 point every 5km/h

Comment: I would advice against using global variables since they are usually considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the speedlimit, `70`, and the current speed, `80`, by the amount per each point. Then you could just subtract those to get points.

```
import math

def speed_check(current_speed):
    max_speed = 70
    if current_speed <= max_speed:
        print("OK")
    elif (current_speed >=130):
        print ("Licence suspended, you total warning points is 12.")
    else:
        points = (current_speed - max_speed) // 5
        print(f"Points: {int(points)}")
```

Comment: Thank you ! My brain couldn't think of the equation to get 1 point per 5kmh

Comment: Or simply `points = (current_speed - max_speed) // 5`

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the speed limit, divide by 5 and then add 1 offset because `1 / 5 = 0`

```
import math

def speed_check(current_speed):
    max_speed = 70
    if current_speed <= max_speed:
        print("OK")
    elif (current_speed >=130):
        print ("Licence suspended, you total warning points is 12.")
    else:
        points = math.floor((current_speed - max_speed) / 5) + 1
        print("Current warning point is {0}".format(points))
```